# Left offset of <select> text

Tags: html, css

According to the design, inputs and selects don't have border and must have similar appearance. I reset all paddings and margins, but  still has some text offset. The main problem is some browsers (e.g. Chrome in Mac OS) don't have this offset, so I can't set padding only for inputs to make them the same. Is there any way to reset this offset?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are using a CSS reset?

Comment: @j08691 The simplest code gives the same result http://jsfiddle.net/bwdtLjrv/3/

Comment: @sareed yes, only CSS reset

Comment: @Alexandra: You  have to add more of your CSS, there are no paddings, select and text input has no offset. In mac/safari.

Comment: @panther Safari and Chrome in Mac OS show pretty nice controls, but in FF (Mac OS), IE10, Chrome, FF in Win it's not so good(

Comment: hmm, some code and maybe the reset you are using might be helpful.